# Databricks Provider: azure-cli: cannot get access token

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

I have the following providers

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.94.0"
    }

    databricks = {
      source  = "databricks/databricks"
      version = "1.37.1"
    }
  }
}
```

In Terraform a create databricks Providers such as the following:

```
provider "databricks" {
  alias                       = "xxx"
  host                        = data.azurerm_databricks_workspace.xxx.workspace_url
  azure_workspace_resource_id = data.azurerm_databricks_workspace.xxx.id
}
```

When I use it such as the following:

resource "databricks_user" "xxxx" {
provider  = databricks.xxx
for_each  = toset([yyyy])
user_name = each.value
}

I get the following error

```
│ Error: cannot read user: default auth: azure-cli: cannot get access token: ERROR: Please run 'az login' to setup account.
│ . Config: host=https:/, azure_workspace_resource_id=/subscriptions/ddd/resourceGroups/rg-hhh/providers/Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces/zzz, azure_client_id=***, azure_tenant_id=ttt. Env: ARM_CLIENT_ID, ARM_TENANT_ID
│
```

My setup is:

- Azure DevOps
- Azure Service Connector
- Use of Terrafrom steps  `TerraformTaskV4@4`

Using PAT, everything works fine, but I would like to use the identidy of the service connector directly: I don't want to store any credentials/tokens. From the error message, it seems like ARM_CLIENT_SECRET is missing which should exist according to [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs#authenticating-with-azure-service-principal):

> There are ARM_* environment variables provide a way to share
> authentication configuration using the databricks provider alongside
> the azurerm provider.

Comment: Since you tried PAT and If you want to avoid passing the identity information and credentials directly, you can use Key Vault to store them and pass them over here by invoking those modules with data modules. @user3579222

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to Access Databricks Provider: azure-cli: cannot get access token and I was successfully able to provision the requirement.

You are facing an error message that indicates a problem with the authentication configuration of the Databricks provider in your Terraform setup. The Databricks provider seems to fail to authenticate with the default credentials, which are required for creating and managing Databricks resources through Terraform.

To use the Databricks provider in your Terraform configuration, you need to configure the authentication correctly. The Databricks provider offers various authentication methods, such as token and Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) authentication. The error indicates that the authentication method is either wrong or absent.

To use this method, you must provide the relevant details such as client ID, client secret, and tenant ID. This method is suitable for Databricks deployments in an Azure environment. Your configuration may resemble the following:

```
 provider "databricks" {
      alias                       = "test"
      host                        = data.azurerm_databricks_workspace.xxx.workspace_url
      azure_workspace_resource_id = data.azurerm_databricks_workspace.xxx.id
    
   azure_client_id     = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.azure_client_id.value
   azure_client_secret = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.azure_client_secret.value
   azure_tenant_id     = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.azure_tenant_id.value
    }
```

Make sure the variables (`azure_client_id`, `azure_client_secret`, `azure_tenant_id`) are correctly defined and populated in the vault.

***My Terraform configruation:***

```
 terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.94.0"
    }
    databricks = {
      source  = "databricks/databricks"
      version = "1.37.1"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_key_vault" "testvk" {
  name                = "testvk"
  resource_group_name = "VkProject-test-rg"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "azure_client_id" {
  name         = "azure-client-id"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.testvk.id
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "azure_client_secret" {
  name         = "azure-client-secret"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.testvk.id
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "azure_tenant_id" {
  name         = "azure-tenant-id"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.testvk.id
}



data "azurerm_databricks_workspace" "xxx" {
  name                = "testcasevk"
  resource_group_name = "VkProject-test-rg"
}

provider "databricks" {
  alias                       = "test"
  host                        = data.azurerm_databricks_workspace.xxx.workspace_url
  azure_workspace_resource_id = data.azurerm_databricks_workspace.xxx.id

  azure_client_id     = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.azure_client_id.value
  azure_client_secret = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.azure_client_secret.value
  azure_tenant_id     = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.azure_tenant_id.value

}

resource "databricks_group" "example" {
  provider = databricks.test
  display_name = "Engtest"
  allow_cluster_create = true
}


// initialize provider at Azure account-level
provider "databricks" {
  alias      = "azure_account"
  host       = "https://adb-70166xxxxxxxx557.17.azuredatabricks.net"
  account_id = "70166xxxxxxxx557"
  auth_type  = "azure-cli"
}

resource "databricks_user" "account_user" {
  provider     = databricks.azure_account
  user_name    = "testuser.onmicrosoft.com"
  display_name = "Test user"
}
```

***Deployment succeded:***

[image]

[image]

Comment: the strange thing: if not using an openId Service Connector it works fine without setting azure_client_id and azure_client_secret

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem using the OpneId Service Connector. I don't want to add client_id/client_secret/tenat_id to the provider which worked fine for non-open id service connector in azure devops

Comment: It doesn't solve your issue using Direct OIDC authentication because Terraform and Azure Databricks, utilizing Azure DevOps' OIDC service connection, is limited and not as seamless as with the AzureRM provider. The Databricks Terraform provider mainly supports Azure AD authentication by using explicit client and tenant details or a Databricks personal access token. @user3579222